# Google v8 memory leaks whithout code executed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks, v8

I try to use the Google V8 library but I found memory leaks.
These memory leaks appeared with this very small code :

```
//I link with v8 in my project settings (Visual studio 2008 )
#include <v8.h>

void test(){ // Never called
   v8::V8::Initialize();
}

void main(){
   exit (0);
}
```

Do you have an idea for stopping memory leaks ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak? Most of the time people who ask this question either don't know what a memory leak is, or they are mistaken when they say they have a leak.

Comment: Do you mean `exit(0)`?

Comment: @john : I know I have a memory leaks, because I activate the memory leaks detection of visual studio. VS display this message _Detected memory leaks!_ in output

Mark Garcia: Yes my mistake. Sorry

Comment: @Hannibal So you used `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`? Unfortunately that doesn't detect memory leaks accurately. Please describe in detail how you detected this memory leak. Please read this link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8bsz08tx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx, it sounds like it's relevant to your situation.

Comment: @john : Yes I use `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` For detecting the memory leaks, I follow this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.90).aspx) and I add this `#ifdef _DEBUG #define new DEBUG_NEW #endif` in the top of my cpp file

Comment: @Hannibal Well like the page I linked to says, this is a false positive, it's not a real memory leak.

Comment: @john Yes I think too it's a false positive. But this "fake memory leak" is visible in the project where this code is added. I created a dll which provide a pretty interface for my application, and the memory leak is visible in my application. This is very bad. So do you know a solution for "hide" this false positive ? Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @Hannibal Not sure I understand, are you not able to just remove the call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`? Also `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` will not be called in a release build, so maybe just switch to a release build.

Comment: @john `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` is also present in my application. So I must keep this command in my application . If I remove this command , I will not be able to see future true memory leaks

Comment: @Hannibal Maybe you can use the checkpoint approach. Create a checkpoint at the begining of main, and a checkpoint at the end of main (but after all destructors for objects local to main), then compare the checkpoints. See here, especially the last paragraph, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tz9b54s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ok, now I know the memory leaks are false positives.
Do you have an idea for hide these leaks if I use my dll inside an application ?
(My application must always enable the memory leaks detection)
So how hide a memory leaks from precise dll ?

Thanks for your great help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the flags _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF and _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF with _CrtSetDbgFlag as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx and remove the explicit call for _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(), it will be called automatically once all processes have been terminated.

<strike>Unfortunately, this does NOT solve the issue for v8 (which is how I arrived at this post), but it does for Qt applications, I am looking for the full answer as well.</strike>

For some reason it works for me now, besides adding

_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF)

At the start of main/WinMain, all I did was call

v8::V8::Dispose()

before program termination.